# Add attribute to XML root node using XSLT (and output existing XSLT with HTML?)

Tags: html, xml, xslt, attributes, root

I apologize for this somewhat as there are similar questions around, however I've attempted to apply all of those and cannot get mine to work with existing stylesheet html output.

I have an existing XML and an existing XSLT which has HTML markup.

I Simply want use the XSLT to also add an attribute to my XML root node but still also output the XSLT HTML.

How would I do this?

**My XML: (I want to add an xmlns attribute to the node: "StockList")**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="do_it.xsl"?>
<StockList>  
<StockItem>
<Item>AX123</Item>
<Description>Firetruck</Description>
<Count>500</Count>
<Order>No</Order>  
</StockItem>  
</StockList>
```

**My XSLT: (do_it.xsl)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:aa="http://www.w3schools.com/MMMXXX">

<xsl:template match="/">  
<html>
<body>
<h2>Things On The Shelf:</h2>
<table border="1">
  <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
    <th style="text-align:left">Item Code</th>
    <th style="text-align:left">Item Description</th>
    <th style="text-align:left">Current Count</th>
    <th style="text-align:left">On Order?</th>
  </tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="aa:StockList/aa:StockItem">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="aa:Item"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="aa:Description"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="aa:Count"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="aa:Order"/></td>
  </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So what do I need to do to my XSLT and WHERE do I need to do it? I've attempted about 15 different 'apply templates' but while I manage to add the attribute I can't also add my html table? :(

Please help.

Comment: A single XSLT (1.0) stylesheet creates a single result tree that can be serialized as HTML, XML or plain text. Having a single XSLT 1.0 stylesheet create some HTML and as well some manipulated XML is not possible. And an `xmlns` "attribute" is not even considered an attribute in the XSLT/XPath data model, it is a namespace declaration. So I am not sure I understand what you want to achieve, you might want to edit your question and show the output(s) you want to create.

Comment: Essentially I just want a namespace declaration for StockList in addition to my html table. From your explanation it seems this isn't possible. :s The reason I haven't declared it from C# is because its a dataset that has used writexml to automate the outpout. You can't append a root namespace on that end so I thought I could do it with XLST.

Comment: If you are using C# to produce the XML using "writexml", you could create some additional C# to change the namespace of all the elements in the XML before sending it out. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb943914.aspx for example.

Answer (score 0):

This has the ring of an [XY problem](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=XY+problem).  Just be assured that you cannot change your source document through XSLT, i.e. adding a new attribute to it so your existing stylesheet code could work.  You also cannot produce an intermediate document and then transform that through XSLT 1.0 (at least as far as I know).

You have to do one of two things:

1. Modify whatever is generating the source XML so it correctly declares the namespace of `<StockList>` for you. You could do this like so:

   ```
   using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
   {
       dataSet.WriteXml(ms);
       ms.Position = 0; // reset!
       XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(ms);
       XNamespace aa = "http://www.w3schools.com/MMMXXX";
       foreach (var el in xd.Root.DescendantsAndSelf())
       {
          el.Name = aa.GetName(el.Name.LocalName);
       }
       xd.Root.Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "aa", aa);
       xd.Save(ms); // or just return the XDocument.ToString(), or return XDocument.CreateReader() as desired
    }
   ```
2. Modify your XSLT so that it doesn't care about namespaces.  For example, change `<xsl:for-each select="aa:StockList/aa:StockItem">` to `<xsl:for-each select="*[local-name()='StockList']/*[local-name()='StockItem']">` and so on everywhere you have a `select` using that namespace prefix.  This is probably the easier fix - I'd go with this solution myself.

Comment: **1.** True, you cannot modify the existing XML - but you can certainly apply two (or more)  XSL transformations to it, either in parallel or in series. -- **2.** Bypassing namespaces is almost never required, and is - by definition - not good practice.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, I don't think it'll be possible to apply multiple transformations in the context of the question - I'm assuming we're talking about browser rendering.  If that's possible in that context, I'd love to know about it.  For __2__ it might be better to use the default namespace, but it sounds like they want this stylesheet to process some data with the NS and some without.  In such a case, I'm not sure which approach to take other than wha tI'm suggesting.

Comment: Under those assumptions, I would agree. It's up to the OP to clarify.

Comment: Dan and Michael, thanks for the replies. Dan you are correct in assuming I only want some data processed with NS and some without.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply two transformations in one style sheet with XSLT 1.0 where the first adds the namespace (you would need to add it to all elements) and the second transforms the result of the first to HTML then you need to perform one step with a variable that is a result tree fragment and then convert that result tree fragment to a node set to apply your `for-each` or other templates. Converting a result tree fragment to a node set can be done with most XSLT processors using the EXSLT extension function `exsl:node-set` (http://exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/index.html), however MSXML used by IE does not support that EXSLT function, only a similar function in a different namespace. Using the `ms:script` extension element [it is however possible to have MSXML support](http://dpcarlisle.blogspot.de/2007/05/exslt-node-set-function.html) `exsl:node-set`, so a complete style sheet doing two transformations looks like

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:aa="http://example.com/ns1"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
  xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  exclude-result-prefixes="aa exsl ms"
  version="1.0">

<ms:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="exsl">
this['node-set'] = function(nodeList) {
  return nodeList;
}
</ms:script>

<xsl:variable name="rtf1">
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="add-namespace"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="add-namespace">
  <xsl:element name="aa:{local-name()}">
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="add-namespace"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">  
<html>
<body>
<h2>Things On The Shelf:</h2>
<table border="1">
  <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
    <th style="text-align:left">Item Code</th>
    <th style="text-align:left">Item Description</th>
    <th style="text-align:left">Current Count</th>
    <th style="text-align:left">On Order?</th>
  </tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($rtf1)/aa:StockList/aa:StockItem">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="aa:Item"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="aa:Description"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="aa:Count"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="aa:Order"/></td>
  </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The example is online at http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2015100701.xml respectively http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2015100701.xsl.

Works as intended with current versions of Firefox, Chrome and IE on Windows 10. Unfortunately Microsoft Edge complains about an error in the XSLT, I am not sure what causes this as Edge like IE 11 uses MSXML 6 to do XSLT. To make it work with Edge I rewrote the style sheet not to make use of `ms:script` and instead use `function-available` and `xsl:when`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:aa="http://example.com/ns1"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
  xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  exclude-result-prefixes="aa exsl ms"
  version="1.0">

<xsl:variable name="rtf1">
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="add-namespace"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="add-namespace">
  <xsl:element name="aa:{local-name()}">
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="add-namespace"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="function-available('exsl:node-set')">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($rtf1)/aa:StockList"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="function-available('ms:node-set')">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ms:node-set($rtf1)/aa:StockList"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <html>
        <body>
          <p>Your XSLT processor does not support exsl:node-set or ms:node-set.</p>
        </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/aa:StockList">  
<html>
<body>
<h2>Things On The Shelf:</h2>
<table border="1">
  <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
    <th style="text-align:left">Item Code</th>
    <th style="text-align:left">Item Description</th>
    <th style="text-align:left">Current Count</th>
    <th style="text-align:left">On Order?</th>
  </tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="aa:StockItem">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="aa:Item"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="aa:Description"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="aa:Count"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="aa:Order"/></td>
  </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That way of course it works with Firefox, Chrome and IE as well.